# Displaying all items in an array in a dynamic textfield [Actionscript 3]

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, dynamic, textfield

I have an array of items which I would like to be displayed within a dynamic textfield to form a high score list.
The amount of items within the arraylist with vary depending on how many high scores are added to it. It is created as standard like this:

```
var lvl1ScoreArray:Array = new Array();
```

And items are added to it within the following code:

```
if (currentLevel == 1)
{
    lvl1highScores.push({score:int(vinylCollected) , player:String(highScoreInput.text)});
    lvl1highScores.sortOn("score", Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC);
}
```

I can obviously trace all the items in the array as follows:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < lvl1highScores.length; i++)
{
    trace(lvl1highScores[i].score, lvl1highScores[i].player);
}
```

But I would like to do this within a dynamic textfield called highScoreTxt.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simple, just create a movie clip with a text field in it with an instance name of `txt`. Name the movie clip `HighScoreTF` and set its linkage to `HighScoreTF` Then your for loop will looking something like so

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < lvl1highScores.length; i++)
{
    var tf:HighScoreTF = new HighScoreTF();
    tf.txt.text = lvl1highScores[i].score + " - " + lvl1highScores[i].player;
    tf.y = i * tf.height; //-- you can replace tf.height with a number to adjust spacing
    addChild(tf);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ronnie, I have tried your answer, but am now getting the following errors

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: HighScoreTF.
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method HighScoreTF.

These are both on the line 'var tf:HighScoreTF = new HighScoreTF();'

Any idea why this has happened?

Comment: Yes..because you haven't set the linkage to `HighScoreTF` on the movie clip I told you to create. Its just a movie clip with a text field in it. You HAVE to set the linkage though

Comment: Oh right okay, do you reckon you could explain setting linkage to me? Not sure what this is!

Comment: Oh, sure. If you've already create the movie clip, locate it in your library panel. Right-click and hit properties. Check the box that says `Export for ActionScript` and where it says `Class` enter `HighScoreTF`